# Has Newton’s Cradle playground been ported to use swift 3 code

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I'm looking for a Xcode 8 port of the Newton’s Cradle playground that's been rewritten in swift 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it manually from the menu:

Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the playground to use Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2 in the following repo
https://github.com/omaralbeik/NewtonsCradle-Swift3